# shell script acting weird (permissions, owner)

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, sms-gateway, aliases

I'm creating a small script "mail_to_sms.sh" that receives emails and sends out the received content through a sms-gateway. Thererfor I use smstools3 on CentOS6.

I modified /etc/aliases in in order to pipe received mails to my script. All the script does is getting the mail body and sending it via the sms-gateway.

In order to understand my problem I have to give you some short introduction to smstools3. The script sendsms which comes with the package smstools3 creates a tmp file (mktemp) and puts it into the folder "/var/spool/mail/outgoing" from there on its handled and sent away. In the smsd.conf file you have to specify a user and a group who uses sendsms. So just files with the right owner and group are sent out. Others just stuck in /var/spool/sms/outgoing and will not be send.

When I run the command directly on bash (logged in with the user specifies in smsd.conf) everything works fine, the user and the group is according to the logged in person and sms is sent.

Whenever my script "mail_to_sms" calls the script "sendsms", the owner and the group of the created file in /var/spool/sms/outgoing is nobody:nobody and will not be send because it's the wrong owner and group.

user and group in smsd.conf are set to user and group nagios
sms_to_mail.sh is also owned by nagios

Every command in sms_to_mail.sh should be run as nagios, right? But why nobody:nobody ???

I'm trying to fix that problems since a week now, testing around, reading in the internet, but I just can't help myself.

Comment: It sounds like NFS file systems are involved, and a root user.  Root gets the privileges of 'nobody' on NFS file systems.  Is any of this a possible factor in your troubles?

Comment: i have come across NFS while looking for a solution but I don't think, that NFS is the problem. The CentOS Server just runs Centreon and NFS was never touched. To be save i added no_root_squash (not sure if I did it right ?!) but that didnt help.

Comment: It sounds like you'll need to turn on tracing within the shell script (`set -x`) and arrange to send standard error to a log file (maybe `exec 2>/tmp/smstest.$$` or something a bit more sophisticated in the way of file name generation) and report on things like the output of the `id` command, etc, until you get the information that tells you what is going wrong.  Check whether any of the tools are setuid or setgid.

Comment: I couldn't figure out why nobody is the owner but with tracing turned on and reading the log, I finally figured out a solution. I adjusted the sendsms script with a "sudo chown nagios:nagios" on the created file. Im not sure if its very secure, because i had to put "nobody ALL=(ALL) /bin/chown, /bin/mv" into /etc/sudoers. What do you think about security ? big problem ?